# Facebook app requests in native Android app: Android notification directs to app page instead of app

Tags: android, facebook, native, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I have an app that uses the Facebook SDK and the requests dialog to sent app requests.

When the app request is received on an Android device running the Facebook app an Android notification is generated - which is all good.

When the user then clicks that notification the Facebook app is started.  Still good.

As the Facebook app starts up you can see the notification jewel (the globe icon within the app) show a new notification (a red badge showing the number 1).

The Facebook app then redirects to my app page and the new notification badge is removed.

I was expecting the user to be shown the Facebook notification itself at this point so that they could click on it to be redirected to my app.

When presented with the app page, the user can click the Facebook notification jewel (even though there is no new notification badge showing) and there they can see the Facebook notification.  They can click on that notification and the Facebook app does then start my app.

This last point indicates that everything is set up correctly for my app in the Facebook dashboard - at least I believe it indicates that.

This is a problem for me as the user won't know how to get from the Facebook app to my app to handle the request.  They won't know to click on the notification jewel as it's no longer highlighted with a badge.

Anyone got any clues for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've now logged a bug report to Facebook for this but it's had its priority set to 'low' so who knows when it'll get looked at.  [Link to the bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/453786104704454)

Comment: I think this is similar to problems others are experiencing but where they're seeing a blank page in the Facebook app with the busy indicator.  That seems to happen is there is no app page associated with the app.  When there is an app page you get the results I've described above.

Comment: I've just heard from Facebook that they're closing my bug report because...

_We are prioritizing bugs based on impact to the developer community. As this bug report has not received much attention from other developers, we are closing it so as to better focus on the top issues. There is a good chance your issue is due to an implementation problem in which case you can try to find help on Stack Overflow_

Is this just something that I'm experiencing?  Have others managed to get the Facebook to redirect directly to their app from a notification?  If so, please comment...